# Cordova Phonegap 2.2.0 VideoPlayer Plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I have been looking around for ages on this but cannot seem to find any solution!

I am trying to have MP4 videos open when a user clicks a div in my Android PhoneGap applications but after further research I found that the HTML5 video tag is not supported and was told to download a plugin call VideoPlayer from here.

https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer

When I run this plugin I get errors relating to several parts of the VideoPlayer.java file.

I have tried adpating some of the plugin code but still do not get any video come up.

Is this plugin not compatible with the latest version of PhoneGap and if not are there any Java gurus that can help me figure out how to get it running natively under Phonegap ?

I get two main errors and some warnings which are shown below:

[image]

The error seems to relate to this line:

URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection();

I have tried to remove that chunk of code (as not looking to load videos from YT but from my local assets) but still no joy getting the video to play.

The config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

Comment: can you post on which lines showing errors of your `VideoPlayer.java` file?

Comment: I have posted the errors to the post. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: what is video url/path ? I just want to know where is your video placed?

Comment: When I alert the url I get "file:///assets/www/res/videos/1.mp4" which is the path to the video files.

Comment: When I click the video I get the error "Unknown chromium error: -6" which is not very helpful :-)

Comment: I posted solution and it is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont remove any chunk of code.

I tried with the same plugin code and it is working for me.

Keep that `VideoPlayer.java` file as it is downloaded with plugin and just press `ctr+shift+O`  this will import required and relevant packages for this plugin file.

Then change your video calling command with,

```
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/res/videos/1.mp4");
```

with Cordova 2.2 3rd step instruction will change to,

```
[3]   In your res/xml/config.xml file add the following line:

    <plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
```

This works for me.

Let me know if there is still issues you are facing.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. The ctr+shift+O worked and brought in the required packages but the videos still do not open up on click. I get the error "Unknown chromium error: -6" whenever I click the div to fire up the video.

Comment: I did do Java development but not since I was last at uni 10 years ago so just a little rusty :-D

Comment: @NeilYoung can I see your `res/xml/config.xml` file?

Comment: I have added the config.xml file in my post above.

Comment: @NeilYoung you can zip your code and send that to me with only required code. I will check and solve that for you.

Comment: Thanks Partik. I will put a HelloWorld together and reproduce and send it over. Do I send it over email or is there an option on this site ?

Comment: @NeilYoung send that to me by email : sm.pratik@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, this is strange. I set up an application to send you and the video works. I have checked the setup of the plugin on the application that does not work and all is fine, as is the video path but the thing still keeps throwing the chromium error!

Comment: @NeilYoung have you import `cordova-2.2.jar` file?

Comment: I fixed it by creating an entirely new project and it has fixed it. I am guessing that the project I was working on had configuration issues/was corrupt.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way Pratik. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Neil Young you are always welcome. If your problem is solved than my efforts worth. You can accept/upvote my solution if you like. Thanks. Ask me anytime when you need my help.

Comment: I have modified this plugin to use the new phonegap 3.0 structure. 
See: https://github.com/justinobney/PhoneGap-Video.git

Install via: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/justinobney/PhoneGap-Video.git